# If Input Field Is Not Empty, Return Error

Tags: php

I have this code in my contact form:

```
$bots = $_POST['bots'];
        if ($bots == '')
            fatal_error($txt['contact_bot_error'], false);
```

What I want to do is, make it so that it does the opposite. If the input isn't empty, return error.

I made it do that there is a question "What is 1 + 1?" and input field for it, with "display:none" styled to it. So only bots should see it. So if they put anything in it, I want it to return an error.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try? Is this your code?

Comment: This is not the cide I used to try. I tried using isset, but kept getting syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you use `isset`?

```
if (isset($_POST['bots'])) {
  fatal_error($txt['contact_bot_error'], false);
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, but syntax error. Should be:     (!isset($_POST['bots']))

Comment: @Xarcell Oh, yes, thanks. I always forget that. Will update post.

Comment: I take it back, it still doesn't return error if something is in that field.

Comment: @Xarcell Oh, misunderstood question. Edited post, now returns error if it is set.

Comment: `isset()` is to check if a variable is set. Not to check if it's empty. `isset()` will return `true` even if the variables's value is `''`.

Comment: @navnav Ah, yes, you are right.  Would it work if I did `if ($_POST['bots'] != '')`?

Comment: That would work. But there is another function that does exactly what the OP asked for. `empty()` - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$bots = $_POST['bots'];

if ( empty( $bots ) === false )
{
   fatal_error($txt['contact_bot_error'], false);
}
```

`empty()` does exactly what you need. It checks the passed string to see if it's empty (value of `''`). If it is, it returns `true`, `false` if it isn't.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I have tried it. Only says "An Error Has Ocurred"

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. Edit your question and show me your (new) code, please.